Solution Explorer не отображает папку с хедерами в CMake targers view
Только начал изучать CMake, столкнулся с проблемой: обозреватель решения VS 2022 в представлении CMake targers не показывает папку include. Подскажите, можно ли её отобразить и, если да, то как.


CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)

# Название проекта и стандарт языка
project(procedural-programming VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

# Установка версии C++
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# Установка путей к исходным файлам и заголовкам
set(SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
set(INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

# Установка исполняемого файла
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME procedural-programming)

# Добавление всех исходных файлов проекта
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "${SOURCE_DIR}/*.cc")
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SOURCES})

# Добавление include-директории
target_include_directories(procedural-programming PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

# Путь для установки
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

Версия MS VS 22: 17.12.2

Такое поведение выглядит логичным, ведь заголовочные файлы не относятся к targets.

Понял, привык к MSBuild, буду отвыкать

¿Зачем отвыкать от MSBuild? А даже если почему-то хочется использовать CMake targers view, то ничего не мешает добавить заголовочные файлы в список исходников, тогда они будут показываться по идее. Еще надо отметить, что CMakeLists выглядит как-то странно, комментарии перед каждой строчкой выглядят так, как будто их очередной gtp писал.
